# if $X$ is a constant discrete random variable, then so is $E(X)$

Tags: probability

show if $X$ is a constant discrete random variable, then so is $E(X)$. I'm asuming the proof is trivial, but I am having torubles understanding what $X$ being constant means? So suppose $X = c$ then I have to show that $E(X) = c$. Relevant formula: $E(X) = \sum_i x_i p(x_i)$

Comment: The expectation of $X$ is in any case a number, "constant."

Comment: For any constant $c$, $\mathbb{E}\left[c\right]=c$.

Comment: rv $X$ is a constant rv if $P(X=c)=1$ for some constant $c$. Its PMF is prescribed by $x\mapsto1$ if $x=c$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise. Can you find $\mathbb EX$ by using the PMF?

Comment: @drhab how did you deduce $X$ is a constant if $P(X=c) = 1$?

Comment: I did not deduce anything, but I gave you the *definition* of a constant random variable.

Comment: @drhab do you have any intuition of this definition? I'm not sure how it follows from "X is constant"

Comment: Excuse. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution) for a definition of constant random variable. What I gave you was the definition of an almost surely constant random variable

Comment: @drhab OK thanks. So using this, $E(X) = \sum_i x_i p(x_i) = \sum_i c \times 1 = \sum_i c$ that's not necessarily $=c$

Comment: It is necessarily $c$ because the indexset only contains one element, hence $\sum_ic=c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X = c$, you can say that there's only one possible outcome, and it happens with a probability of 1. So the sum in your formula will only have one term.

$$\sum_i x_i p(x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^1 c \cdot 1 = c \cdot 1 = c.$$